# How to change the color of certain cells based on its value in listview

Tags: listview, winapi, colorize

I have created a listview in C. The cells color should be changed based on value entered in them. already i'm using the following code but it's altering the whole row neither the cell it self nor based on its value.

```
case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
                 {
                     NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* plvCstDrawPtr = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>(nmheader);

                     if( plvCstDrawPtr->nmcd.dwDrawStage == CDDS_PREPAINT )
                     {
                         return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
                     }
                     else if( plvCstDrawPtr->nmcd.dwDrawStage == CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT )
                     {
                         if( plvCstDrawPtr->nmcd.dwItemSpec & 1 )
                         {
                             plvCstDrawPtr->clrTextBk = RGB( 255, 0, 0);
                         }
                     }
                     break;
                 }
```

i need a code to change the color based on value not based on index.

Comment: Use `LVM_GETITEM` to get the value. If your listview is owner-data, then you'll need to look up whatever you use to populate the listview. Good luck!

Comment: I can get the value, i want to colorize cell based on the value

Comment: Then I'm not sure where your confusion is. You have the value, and you have the code to colorize text; put the two together.

Comment: I want to colorize an specific cell not the whole row. the code shown above makes row(including all the cells in row) alternatively red.

Comment: You are not handling the `CDDS_SUBITEM` related drawing stages. `CDDS_PREPAINT` needs to return `CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW` so you receive `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT`, which then needs to return `CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW` so you receive `CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT`. Read the documentation: [Custom Draw Overviews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625865.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, `CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` helped. Using `nmcd.dwItemSpec` as row index and `iSubItem` as column index I could colorize an specific cell.